# Error during insert data in mysql WordPress database error?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I got a error during inserting data into `MySql` Database.

data are inserted successfully but with given error `[WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near] '`

following query i used for inserting record in database.

```
$sqldata = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `wp_make_details`      
                        (`c_id`, `post_id`, `make_name`, `year`, `model_name`)
                        values (NULL,".$post_id.",'".$all_make."', '".$all_year."', '". $all_model."')");
```

echo query result with values like

```
INSERT INTO `wp_make_details` (`c_id`, `post_id`, `make_name`, `year`, `model_name`) values (NULL,'15904','Yamaha', '2006', 'Stratoliner, Stratoliner S, Stratoliner Midnight, Roadliner, Roadliner SÂ , Roadliner Midnight, Road Star, Road Star Midnight, Road Star Silverado, Road Star Midnight Silverado, V-Star 650 Custom, V-Star 650 Midnight Custom, V-Star 650 Classic, V-Star 650 Silverado, V-Star 1100 Custom, V-Star 1100 Midnight CustomÂ , V-Star 1100 Classic, V-Star 1100 Silverado, Road Star Warrior, Road Star Midnight Warrior, V-Max, Virago 250, Royal Star Venture, Royal Star Midnight VentureÂ , Royal Star Tour Deluxe, FJR1300A, FJR1300AE, YZF600R, YZF-R1, YZF-R1 50th Anniversary Edition, YZF-R1 LE, YZF-R1Â LE, YZF-R6, YZF-R6 50th Anniversary Edition, YZF-R6S, MT-01Â , XJR1300Â , FZ1, FZ1 Naked, FZ6Â , MT-03Â , XT225, TW200, YZ450F, YZ450F 50th Anniversary Edition, YZ250Â , YZ250F, YZ250F 50th Anniversary Edition, YZ125Â , YZ85Â , WR450F, WR250F, TT-R250, TT-R230Â , TT-R125LEÂ , TT-R125LÂ , TT-R125EÂ , TT-R125, TT-R90E, TT-R90Â , TT-R50EÂ , PW80Â , PW50, Majesty, Morphous, Vino, Vino 125, BW's, X-Max 125Â ')
```

i don't know what happen also don't know why error is coming of `MariaDB`, i found in **google** but i can not get solution for this.

is anyone know about it help me please ?

Comment: isn't this "c_id" and uto_increment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i resolved this issue i missed `mysql_real_escape_string()`

and by using this my completed query is

```
$sqldata = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `wp_make_details`      
                            (`c_id`, `post_id`, `make_name`, `year`, `model_name`)
                            values (NULL,".$post_id.",'".$all_make."', '".$all_year."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($all_model)."')");
```

And now is working perfect.